# Category & Product Page detection

Tags: php, category, magento-1, template

I am using the below on my 2columns-left.phtml template to detect whether the page is a category page or a product page.

```
  <?php $_catDetails = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

  <?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();?>
  <?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();?>

        <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category')){ ?>
            <?php echo 'I am a category page'; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php echo 'I am not a category page'; ?>
        <?php } ; ?>
```

However this appears to be also echoing on a product page!

Can anyone explain what i am doing wrong, as i thought the first line would detect the Mage page type registration.

Thanks
Kirsty

Update I have also tried the below:

```
<?php if($this->getCategoryPage()) {
            echo 'This is a category page';
        }else {
            echo 'this is not a category page';
        } ?>
```

Comment: Do you mind giving me some context on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check like this:

```
<?php 
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
if ($action == 'catalog_category_view') {
   //you are in the category page
} elseif ($action == 'catalog_product_view') {
   //you are in the product page
} else {
   //you are somewhere else.
}
```

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for this. It appears however, that this only worked on the category view and not the product view?? What is the difference between the catalog cat view and the product cat view? Thankyou :)

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. In the `elseif` part I had `product_category_view` instead of `catalog_product_view`. Now it should be OK.

Comment: Hi Marius. Wonderful. This seems a nicer way to write the requirements. Great help.

Comment: Is there any benefits in using the above method over the one below??

Comment: @KirstyMarks use this because Marius said so..

Comment: I think the effects are the same in this example, but the way I described can be easily extended to other pages without to go through all kind of tricks.

Answer (score 0):

When you go from category page to product then category registry also created so add additional check of `Mage::registry('current_product')` will do the trick here

```
<?php $_catDetails = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>

  <?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getName();?>
        <?php echo Mage::registry('current_category')->getParentId();?>

        <?php if(Mage::registry('current_category') && !Mage::registry('current_product')){ ?>
            <?php echo 'I am a category page'; ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php echo 'I am not a category page'; ?>
        <?php } ; ?>
```

Comment: I will accept your answer in 5 mins when i can :)